# Linking to other Music SE questions

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, chat, comments

Question
[Should sight-reading be emphasized less for piano instruction with new developments in technology](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/110288/should-sight-reading-be-emphasized-less-for-piano-instruction-with-new-developme)
appeared to me as similar to another question, so I put a link in the comment. As there was many comments, eventually a mod moved all comments to chat. This is understandable, however the other question is no longer displayed as a linked one. Does it make sense? I didn't want to answer the question, I didn't have much add to other answers, but I think internal linking is something very important for the site in general, so it feels bad they are so volatile.

I don't even know what question to ask. What is the best practice in that case?

Edit: Following @Richard's advice I asked a question on stack wide meta [How can I link other questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360382/how-can-i-link-other-questions) but it seems to me that SE doesn't have a solution.

Comment: This would be a good point to bring up to the Stack-wide Meta page. A cursory search for a similar question didn't bring anything up, and I'd bet others would be interested in this, as well. It seems odd that we'd need another user to re-add the link (which someone thankfully has.)

Comment: As a temporary solution, you could link in the other direction. Rather than a comment-link in "Should sight-reading ...", put the comment-link it what you originally planned as the target post. Also, IMO, it's fair to edit the OP and add a note at the bottom pointing to the related post. That would be the most permanent solution.

Comment: @Aaron So basically, new question Q1 and old question Q2, your last suggestion is to edit Q2 to add in a link to Q1 at the bottom, so that Q1 (which is still active) would have a somewhat permanent link to Q2? (I had to add nickname in to have an idea of what I was writing)

Comment: Yeah, my comment wasn't entirely clear. I meant either: (1) Add a comment to Q2 including a link to Q1 (the reverse of what you originally did), or (2) Edit Q1 and add a note to the bottom of the post saying something like "related question: <link>". In either case, each question will show up in the "Linked" list for its partner.

Comment: You who are willing to post on Meta, I salute you! But that aside, I do think there are situations where it's appropriate to edit the OP and just add a link there. I think the particular question that brought the issue up would be fair game in this regard. I would add an "<hr>" at the end of the post and then put the link with a little note saying something like "this post may be of interest."